# Does segfaults mean bad memory

Tags: centos, memory, php, hardware, segmentation-fault

This is a brand new server with a new install and fresh compile of Apache/PHP with nothing crazy. Just a WordPress site hosted and I get the following.

Could this just mean bad RAM? If so how can I test it without taking the box down.

I have noticed some weird memory issues with PHP despite making the php.ini settings unlimited.

```
conftest[31039]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000405088 sp 00007fff92152090 error 4 in conftest[400000+a4000]
    conftest[26375]: segfault at 1 ip 0000000000405088 sp 00007fffa5b0b450 error 4 in conftest[400000+a4000]
    php[10669]: segfault at aec69ff1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff39245950 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[14634]: segfault at 0 ip 000000000073ea24 sp 00007ffffaa24c60 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[17315]: segfault at 9e979531 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff877ba610 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[2804]: segfault at 108afe2a1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff53cb5210 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[6726]: segfault at 75dd5051 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007ffffc9f2850 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[7701]: segfault at ffffffff ip 00000000007150cf sp 00007fff8e927650 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[13827]: segfault at 28 ip 0000000000715fa0 sp 00007fff4d9dabd0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[12324]: segfault at ffffffff ip 00000000007150cf sp 00007fff56f62aa0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[10609]: segfault at 7f9465fe9231 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff83e6bd00 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[18771]: segfault at 142dcfdc1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff77d693d0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[9509]: segfault at 12f8ebf71 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007ffff6030d80 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[26998]: segfault at ffffffff ip 00000000007150cf sp 00007fff66777760 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[4820]: segfault at ffffffff ip 00000000007150cf sp 00007fffdc9b7020 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[4663]: segfault at bd7b35a1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fffaaa32b80 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[4859]: segfault at a5ff560 ip 0000000000715e77 sp 00007fff5f232650 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[1020]: segfault at 7f12ce5ba831 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fffb41cc5e0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[17655]: segfault at 122a87e81 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fffbe942040 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[11928]: segfault at 7f21b1103e31 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff5ef70ae0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[29523]: segfault at c42cb5a1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff93335a50 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[7693]: segfault at 7f511f5fe431 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fffb9802fc0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[4186]: segfault at 7f7df67db431 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff1dcb1f10 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[15296]: segfault at abfa3ea1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff88ec89e0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[15277]: segfault at ffffffff ip 00000000007150cf sp 00007fff8419b4c0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[6223]: segfault at f05b1401 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff96517ea0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[9998]: segfault at 1535be691 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff1888ffd0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[15664]: segfault at 6fdc57f1 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff7c39da10 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[20894]: segfault at ffffffff ip 00000000007150cf sp 00007fff03b66430 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[20485]: segfault at 7ff9b7be7631 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fffb8a7e760 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
    php[10195]: segfault at 105ae7d21 ip 0000000000759ac1 sp 00007fff43ed91f0 error 4 in php[400000+6dd000]
```

Comment: Boot into `memtest` or `memtest86` and let it check for some time.

Comment: In case you didn't know, "bad memory" (and this sure looks like it) is often "memory that's come loose from its socket". Do the memtest and if that fails, try removing and re-seating the RAM first; 'tis a bit less expensive than replacing it.

Comment: If this a server, what does the hardware-log of that server show about ECC errors?

Answer (score 2):

It can mean bad RAM, but I don't know of any method of testing memory without downtime. If you can afford said downtime, do as ott suggested and let memtest run for as long as you can.

Comment: Wasn't there a tool (forget it's name) that would run in the background to check/scan for hardware issues like RAM faults?

Comment: If a program is running while a kernel is resident, it cannot check the locations the kernel lives in. If you suspect hardware memory errors, no memory should be trusted (or, all memory must be tested). Memory tests on a live system cannot do the whole jobe.

Comment: You can't reliably check memory while it's constantly written to.